# Processing js - Level Scroll

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

im trying to make a map scroll with the mouse and i have some issues/doubts i wanted to ask.

1. is there a better way to design more complex levels? i kinda think this way is not very good in terms of performace.
2. the scroll has some issues; if you see, when we scroll to the right, in the end all the frist row moves to the left a little. also happens when we scroll to the left. the first square moves to the right. is there a way to prevent this?

here is my code :

```
/* @pjs preload="images/grass.png" */

var level = [];
var level_1 = [
    "egggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggge",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
    "egggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggge",

];
var wid;
var hi;


var Ground = function(x, y, label) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.label = label;
};
Ground.prototype.draw = function() {
    if(this.label == "g") {
        PImage name;
        name = loadImage("images/grass.png");

        image(name, this.x, this.y);
    }
};


void makeLevel() {
    for(var i = 0; i < level_1.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < level_1[i].length; j++) {
            switch(level_1[i][j]) {
                case "g" :
                    level.push(new Ground(j*15, i*15, "g"));
                    break;
                case "e" :
                    level.push(new Ground(j*15, i*15, "e"));
                    break;
            }
            wid = level_1[i].length-1;
        }
    }
}

makeLevel();

void draw() {
    background(0);

    for(var i=0; i < level.length; i++) {
        level[i].draw();

        if(mouseX <= width && mouseX >= width-15 && level[wid].x > width-15) {
            level[i].x -= 5;
        }
        if(mouseX <= 15 && mouseX >= 1 && level[0].x < 0) {
            level[i].x += 5;
        }
        if(mouseY >= height-15 && mouseY <= height && level[level.length-1].y > height-20) {
            level[i].y -= 5;
        }
        if(mouseY <= 15 && mouseY >= 1 && level[0].y < 0) {
            level[i].y += 5;
        }
    }
}
```

thanks in advance =)

Comment: When I try to run this code, I get a compilation error: `unexpected token:[`. Are you sure you're using Processing.js? Can you post a fiddle or something?

Comment: i dont know how fiddle works. and as this is processing.js i think you have to have the pde file and also the processing.js file so i dont think it would work on fiddle. only if i could upload the files somewhere and i dont have any way to do that right now =X

Comment: I'd like to help, but I can't run your code. What version of the Processing editor are you using? Do you have a link to this code running somewhere? The best way to get help with JavaScript is by posting a jsfiddle, especially if other people can't just copy and paste your code to run it.

Comment: i'm making this locally. no worries. i'll see if i can do this work on fiddle

Comment: ok, i guess i found a way. 
linnk to khan academy - https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/mousescroll/2926105344

if you see, if you scroll to the far right and than back, there is an issue and also if you scroll down and back.

any help is welcome

Comment: Thanks for making a version we can use, but I don't really understand your question. Right now I only see code for moving to the right. I don't see any code for scrolling back.

Comment: sorry... ill save it =) im just testing and here's what i can see. every time i scroll the first "square" is pushed exactly 5 pixels to the right and down also =X know how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for part 2 of your question:

To your code in Khan Academy, add "+0.5" to the x position of the grass. It should look like this:

```
level.push(new Ground(j*20 + 0.5, i*20, "g")); // grass
```

I can't really explain why this works, and it's probably not the best solution, since it moves the grass 0.5px, but it is a quick fix to avoid the problem with one row of grass suddenly disappearing.